# JSF Java Server Faces dynamic loading of component

Tags: java, jsf, wildfly

I am attempting to load a custom component(descending from `UIInput`).  I then encode an `html` input back to the client.  My component loader is thus:

```
@FacesComponent("TomsWidgetComponent")
@SessionScoped
public class TomsWidgetComponent {
public TomsInput getNewInput(UIComponent parent)
{
  ExpressionFactory factory = getFacesContext().getApplication().getExpressionFactory();

    TomsInput newComponent = (TomsInput) getFacesContext().getApplication().createComponent(getFacesContext(), "org.tom.example.toms.TomsInput", "org.tom.example.toms.TomsInput");
    String newId = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().createUniqueId();
    newComponent.setId(newId);
    elements.put(newId, newComponent);

    newComponent.setInputData(new InputData());

    ValueExpression valueExpression = factory.createValueExpression(getFacesContext().getELContext(),"#{tomsInput.string}",String.class);
    newComponent.setValueExpression("value", valueExpression);

    getChildren().add(newComponent);
    pushComponentToEL(getFacesContext(), newComponent);
    return newComponent;
}
```

`html`:

```
<"input  type="tel"  id="j_id2"  oninput="mojarra.ab(this,event,0,'execute',0)" /input >"
```

The input shows up just fine, but `ajax` event never seems show up in my component. I've tried several permutations, with the key on `setValueExpression`, and adding behavior listeners.

`...`

Ive gotten passed the exceptions but the Ajax now coming back from the form is causing my component to reload.  It's content is:

```
tomswidgetform=tomswidgetform&j_id2=fffdsdfgbg&javax.faces.ViewState=-6270730402975544133%3A7227399941332846704&javax.faces.source=j_id2&javax.faces.partial.event=input&javax.faces.partial.execute=j_id2%20j_id2&javax.faces.behavior.event=change&AJAX%3AEVENTS_COUNT=1&javax.faces.partial.ajax=true
```

Any idea what might be wrong?  Thanks.